# How can I do null validation in group of checkbox to submit event in java script in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@model TechCourier.Customer.BO.CustomerAddressBO

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAddress", "Customer", new { @onsubmit = "check(this.form.AddressType)" }))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID)
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          @{Html.RenderAction("Address", "Address", new { addressID = 0 });}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TextLeft">
          @Html.Label("Address Type")
          @Html.ValidationMessage("Addresstype")
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="check">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.AddressTypeID)
            {
              <br />
              <input type="checkbox" name="AddressType" value="@item.AddressTypeID" />@item.AddressType
            }
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="CustomerID" value="@ViewData["CustomerID"]" />
        </td>  
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
}

<script>
</script>
```

This is my razor partial popup view. Here i want to do null client validation for group of checkbox in javascript for submit event. I done popup jquery and with custom html helper so submit button customize in htlm helper.

Comment: What do you mean _"do null client validation for group of checkbox"_? Are you wanting to make sure at least one checkbox is checked?

Comment: Yes i want to make sure at least one checkbox

Comment: You creating checkboxes that have no relationship to your model (they are named `AddressType`) so you wont be able to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in conjunction with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`. You will need to handle the `.submit()` event and check if any are checked. If not, cancel the submit and display a message (and handle the checkboxes `.change()` event to remove the message)